# Firebase Storage Web file access just for signed in users

Tags: angular, firebase, web, firebase-storage

I am trying to give access to a firebase storage file from the frontend (angular) just for signed in users.
So i set the storage rule to `allow read: if request.auth != null;`
But how did the frontend gets access. i could use getDownladUrl() but then anyone gets access, i dont want to write the download url with the token in the frontend.
Perhaps I can use the url without the token.
I could not find any code example for this on the web.
Does anyone have an idea how to do that?